# Is there a cooldown for Nezumi's superpower?

Tags: juuni-taisen

In *Juuni Taisen*, Nezumi have the superpower of the Hundred Paths, which means he can create a **game save**/**life save** at a certain time and if he gets killed or something, he can return to the save point and start over again with all his memories retained and others' wiped. He says that he has at most 100 chances to start from the save point.

Since he can make a backup game save at any moment, then he in fact has infinite chances to start over. Say he creates a game save at time *t*, after he has exhausted 100 paths, he can create another game save at time *t*+1s or *t*+1ms shortly after his last save point, and then he has another 100 chances. In this manner, he legitly has infinite chances.

What's confusing is that in practice, he seems to try only 100 times. For example, after the battle royale, the host gave him an interview. He didn't want to tell the host about his ability, so he used his Hundred Paths, but after [100 failures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJfLmy5OV6s), he gave up and told the story. Why didn't he just keep using his Hundred Paths? Then he may be able to avoid divulging his secret ability.

Is there a cooldown for Nezumi's superpower?